# Android AVD is giving an "Unfortunately [App] Has Stopped Working" error

Tags: java, android

I have just started learning to develop Android apps. In this project, I have used a Menu whose second option leads to a class called TextPlay. This works just fine till the time I add the line,

```
display.setText(input.getText().toString());
```

in TextPlay.java.

TextPlay.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class TextPlay extends Activity{ 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.text);
        Button chkCmd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bResults);
        ToggleButton passTog = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
        EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
        TextView display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

        display.setText(input.getText().toString());

    }
}
```

Text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25sp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etCommands"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Type a Command"
        android:password="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bResults"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="Button" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tbPassword"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="ToggleButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Trying to getText before the value of the text is actually available; NullPointerException;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

Your `TextView` seems to be called `R.id.tvResults` but in your `findViewById()` you named it `R.id.tvDisplay`, thus it doesn't exists and returns `null`, that's why you're seeing that exception.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `TextView` in your layout that has the id "tvDisplay".

Comment: Sorry, I think I've been following a tutorial a bit blindly. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In Text.xml,
you have saved it with different name:
 **android:id="@+id/tvResults"**

correct it with 
**android:id="@+id/tvDisplay**

you are getting this error because their is no tvDisplay id in R.java file. that is why it is sending null exception.